# How to test UIImagePickerControllerMediaType for kUTTypeImage?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4, cfstring, uiimagepickercontrollermediatype

In the delegate method of `UIImagePickerViewController`, I want to test for the media type.

This worked in **Swift 3**:

```
switch info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? NSString {

    case .some(kUTTypeImage):
    //...
}
```

But in **Swift 4**, it throws an error:

> Expression pattern of type '`CFString`' cannot match values of type '`NSString`'

I changed it to this without error, but the type conversion doesn't look elegant:

```
switch info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String {

    case .some(kUTTypeImage as NSString as String):
    //...
}
```

I tried to shorten it:

```
switch info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? NSString {

    case .some(kUTTypeImage as NSString):
    // ...
}
```

But this throws the error again:

> Expression pattern of type 'CFString' cannot match values of type
>   'NSString'

a) Why does the shorter version throw an error but the longer version doesn't?

b) Is there a more elegant (shorter) way to write this?

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the dictionary element to `CFString`.

```
let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! CFString

switch mediaType {
case kUTTypeImage:
    //
default: break
}
```

Strangely enough, if I try to conditionally unwrap `mediaType`, Xcode will complain:

> Conditional downcast to `CoreFoundation` type '`CFString`' will always succeed

...and if I try to use simply `as CFString`, as it "will always succeed":

> '`Any?`' is not convertible to '`CFString`'; did you mean to use '`as!`' to force downcast?

Strange, seems like the compiler is a little confused. Anyway, it's one of the few instances where force unwrapping *is* the most elegant solution.

Comment: If for some reason the media retrieval fails and the info dictionary doesn't have the property then it throws an exception. Hence I'd prefer to not force unwrap here.

Comment: You can check before the unwrapping if the value is `nil`.

Comment: True that. However I will file a bug with Apple.